# Positioning text in div

Tags: css, html

The screen has list of 5 images arranged horizontally. Below each image, I have a div to display the name of the image. 
I have word-wrap for image name, so in case of long names they spread across multiple lines.

The issue here is, when image name spreads across multiple lines, other small image name are pulled down. That is all the other image names line up with the bottom of the longest name. I want all image names to be displayed just below the image.

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS.

Comment: Can you please post your code on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aplly 'vertical-align:top;' on the elements who hold the text.

Answer (score 1):

you can use table

```
<table align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr><td>img</td></tr>
<tr><td>img name</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: dont use table for layout. its bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Give a height to the li and add `float:left;`

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a table to separate the trs, or group the images in a floated div, then clear, then group the text in another floated div.